# Write Java Method Signature with Annotated paramaters with JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-generation, eclipse-jdt

I am writing an eclipse plug-in which generates code.  I am leveraging eclipse jdt to gen out classes, fields, and methods.  One of the requirements I have is to generate methods with annotated paramaters...

```
public returnType foo(@someAnnotation int id)
{
     .....
     .....
}
```

Does anybody know how to write out the @someAnnotation using JDT?  To write out normal parameters in JDT you could do something like the following

```
Signature.createTypeSignature("int", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging the creation of a type signature with an annotation and inspect the parameters passed to createTypeSignature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have tried this.  The createTypeSignature() function does validation on the String that is passed to it.  When it sees something like the following it throws an exception...

```
Signature.createTypeSignature("@PathParam(\"custId\") int");
```

Hope this clears it up, and thanks for the response.  Let me know if you have any other ideas.